# Unable to print href in web scraper, no errors

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am able to extract the names from the html however trying to get the href links isn't working out. I am needing to get it so it prints the link next to the name its attached too. before I can do that I need to be able to print the link in the first place.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

user_input = input("character: ")
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.marvel.com/search")

search_input_xpath = "//input[@placeholder='Search']"
search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, search_input_xpath)))
search_input.send_keys(user_input)

first_item_in_auto_suggest_area_xpath = "//div[contains(@id,'react-autowhatever')]/ul"
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, first_item_in_auto_suggest_area_xpath)))
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

section = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-list p.card-body__headline a")))


character = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-list p.card-body__headline a")
for character_tag in character:
    print(character_tag.text)

href_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-list p.card-body__headline href")
for href in href_elements:
    print(href.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access an attribute using a css selector.

I'd try first to change `href` to `a`:

```
href_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-list p.card-body__headline a")
```

Comment: damn that fixed it fully! Thank you so much. such a tiny mistake on my part haha. got it working. Ive now got it that character has 2 prints now. one is the character_tag.text and then straight after i have character_tag.get_attribute("href") and it worked

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^